# how to get form progress after submition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to somehow track the progress of a form submitting. My script uploads a file using a simple form with enctype multipart/form-data. After firing the submit function I want to somehow track and handle the progress of the current upload. For instance by default in Chrome it shows on the bottom left corner (Uploading: 10%) when my form is "uploading". How can I create a handle for forms current progress?

The only thing I have so far for the form is detecting the submit.

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 alert("submitting");
 });
```

Comment: Instead of trying to write sth by yourself you can use http://valums.com/ajax-upload/.

Comment: Well im required to make it myself because I need it for commercial use.

Comment: Not really. It is under MIT license, so you can use it in commercial, not open-source projects (for example jQuery is under MIT too).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general approach:

1. Client: Start a timer
2. Client: Submit form data
3. Client: In timer handler, send a request via AJAX and poll for the current status of the submission
4. Client: Restart timer, until the submission is completed.

On the server, you need two request handlers and a shared memory structure. The first request handler processes the request and updates the memory structure with the current status.

The second handler reads the shared memory structure and returns the current content to the timer callback running on the client.

Comment: Thats a very helpful approach, but I dont know how I would do the server side. I have used any shared memory structures in PHP. Also my php script uses move_uploaded_file (); to get the file and write it. how can one even get the current contents status with this?

Comment: That's a new question which some PHP guru can probably answer.